# How to search an object list for a specific attribute value that exists in another list of objects

Tags: python

I have two lists

```
list1 = [obj1, obj2, ... objn] # len(list1) == N
list2 = [obj1, obj2, ... objm] # len(list2) == M
```

here's a json representation of obj:

```
obj = {
   "a1": 0,
   "a2": 1,
   "a3": 2
}
```

How would I determine the objects from `list2` with the same value for `obj["a1"]` as those in `list1`? Note it's possible to have multiple occurrences of this. The objects in both lists are formatted the same.

I am only interested in seeing if the value for a **certain object attribute** from one list can be found in another

For example

```
list1 = [
   {
      "a1":0,
      "a2":5,
      "a3":4
   },
   {
      "a1":2,
      "a2":3,
      "a3":1
   }
   ...
] 

list2 = [
   # first object
   {
      "a1":0,
      "a2":3,
      "a3":1
   },
   # second object
   {
      "a1":3,
      "a2":1,
      "a3":0
   }
   ...
]
```

In this case, the first object in `list2` contains the same attribute value for `obj["a1"]` as `list1`

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit, what do you mean by attribute value. Do you want to get value in list1 where list2 first object a1 matches in list1 ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi I want to search list2's objects and see if a particular property/attribute of an object also exists in list1's list of objects. Note that both lists contain objects that are formatted the same

Comment: Can you use pandas as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Check Pandas, you can easily transform the lists to pandas and from there, doing what you need is pretty straight forward.

Index the two pandas with "a1", and then check [this link to get intersection](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.intersection.html)

try this; (I have not run the code. but this should work!)

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)

df1.set_index("a1",inplace=True)
df2.set_index("a1",inplace=True)

df1.index.intersection(df2.index)
```

This should give you the list of intersections

Answer (score 1):

using pandas you can try this

```
list1 = [
   {
      "a1":0,
      "a2":5,
      "a3":4
   },
   {
      "a1":2,
      "a2":3,
      "a3":1
   }
] 

list2 = [
   # first object
   {
      "a1":0,
      "a2":3,
      "a3":1
   },
   # second object
   {
      "a1":3,
      "a2":1,
      "a3":0
   }
] 

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list2)

a1 = df2[df2['a1'].isin(df1['a1'])]
a1.to_json(orient='records', lines=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to simply go through a double loop:

```
for obj1 in list1:
    for key in obj1:
        for obj2 in list2:
            if (obj1[key] == obj2[key]):
                # Do what you want
```

Comment: you missed a colon on Line 1 :D

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking into different libraries and you may find an answer. However you can play around with dictionaries to achieve the same results. Let me know if you have any issues with this method.

```
def get_groups(list1, list2):

    # assuming the obj are dictionaries in lists 1 & 2
    # we store entries into the known_data as 
    # (category, value) : [obj_references]
    # eg known_data = {('a1', 0) : [obj1, obj23, obj3]}

    known_data = {}

    for obj in list1:
        for category, value in obj.items():
            key = (category, value)
            entry = known_data.get(key, []) or []
            entry.append(obj)
            known_data[key] =  entry

    # now we can iterate over list2 and check to see if it shares any keys
    # for groups we store our common key (category, value)
    # and map to a 2D array [ [list1 objs] , [list2 objs]] 
    groups = {}

    for obj in list2:
        for category, value in obj.items():
            key = (category, value)
        
            if key not in known_data:
                continue
        
            entry = groups.get(key) or [[], [known_data[key]]]
            entry[0].append(obj)
            groups[key] = entry
            
    return groups
```

Comment: function code needs to be indented :D